# displaying a sprite on a tile map XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I am learning XNA but having some dificulty in placing the sprite onto the tilemap.

Here is what ive tried :

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch,int tileWidth,int tileHeight)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw( texture , position , Color.White );
    }// This code draws the sprite but the sprite is not on the tile map but outside it.


public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch,int tileWidth,int tileHeight)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw( texture , new Rectangle( ( int )position.X * tileWidth , ( int )position.Y * tileHeight , tileWidth , tileHeight ) , Color.White );
    }// And this code does nothing, doesnt even draw the sprite
```

This is 2D array:

```
int[ , ] map = {
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, },
                   };
```

Where 0 = a wall &
      1 = pathway

Please show me or advise me on how to go about drawing the sprite only on the map?

Thanks

EDIT: The problem i am having is that the sprite(black square on bottom right) if moved left, goes behind the brown(which is prt of the tile map). How do i make it so that it moves on top of the tile map instead of underneath

[image: In game picture]

Comment: Done something similar but for the Nintendo DS. Used a custom font file but replaced characters with sprites, so an `X` would be a wall and a `Z` would be an enemy. You'll want to loop over the array drawing your sprites where `i = X` etc...

Comment: You can stop that happening by setting the `SpriteSortMode` before drawing

Comment: Thanks Duane!!!! But now i cant accept answer. Would like to know will i still set collision normally for the sprite on tilemap?

Comment: I'll make it an answer so you can accept it. I assume the collision will remain the same, have you tested it yet?

Comment: yes ive tested it but its doing some craze stuff, like it remains ontop of some brown tiles and goes underneath oters. I dont know why though

Comment: Have you set a sortmode for the brown tiles too?

Comment: yes i set the sortmode for both as well but that doesnt work at all.

Comment: This might be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503217/defining-two-spritesortmodes

Comment: aaah i fixed it, just called the drawturtle method after the map was created, and it worked :) Thanks Duane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your sprite from going behind the brown tiles you'll need to set the `SpriteSortMode` property before `SpriteBatch.Begin()` is called

Further reading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.spritesortmode.aspx